# How to create custom post page in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wpbakery

I want to create a post page template for my website.

I am currently using the theme's default post page. I created a template (Template 1) with wp-bakery in  pages section with JegTheme addons :
[image: template]

When a users enters a blog post, they should see that post with the template that I prepared.

I tried to change it from settings -> reading -> Post page: Template 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

settings -> reading -> Post page: Template 1
this should set template 1 as a blog page for your website. Also, check here if your page is selected in "posts page".